# What are the possible way to set Global Http Proxy in iOS setting programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, configuration-files, http-proxy, apple-configurator

I want to set the Global Http Proxy setting in iOS setting within my application. One possible way is creating a configuration profile with the apple configurator tool and install that profile. But for this device will be **supervised only**.
 
Is there any other way, where I don’t need the supervised device?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no other way. You will need to create a configuration profile and install it on the device.